# How to rorate the image of a background in CSS?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a hexagon background image. I want to rotate the hexagon image so that the dashed line moves to a different side.

I tried to use the `::nth-child` pseudo-class, but it did not work.

Here is what I have done

```css
.node::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: 120px 120px;
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/4p1pQtF/Component-1.png');
}

.node {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 120px !important;
    width: 120px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

.node::nth-child(2) {
    transform: roate(60);
}
.node::nth-child(3) {
    transform: roate(120);
}

.node::nth-child(4) {
    transform: roate(180);
}

.node::nth-child(5) {
    transform: roate(240);
}
```

```html
<div class="node">

  1

</div>

<div class="node">
  2
</div>

<div class="node">
3
</div>

<div class="node">
4
</div>


<div class="node">
5
</div>
```

How can I rotate the hexagon image in the box 60degree for each node?

#### Updated

I also tried the following

```
.node:nth-child(2)::before {
    transform: roate(60deg);
}

.node:nth-child(3)::before {
    transform: roate(120deg);
}

.node:nth-child(4)::before {
    transform: roate(160deg);
}
.node:nth-child(5)::before {
    transform: roate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: `:` not `::` and you are missing `deg` and you need to target the pseudo element (closing as typo)

Comment: @TemaniAfif that also did not work.

Comment: use online tool to validate your code or rely on some editor that can highlight syntax issue. `rotate` and not `roate`

Comment: thank you! this is what actually worked ```.node:nth-child(2)::before {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you had 3 different typos.

1. You used `::nth-child` instead of `:nth-child` with just one colon
2. You used `roate` instead of  `rotate`
3. you were missing `deg` from `rotate(180deg)` and just had a number in there

```css
.node::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: 120px 120px;
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/4p1pQtF/Component-1.png');
}

.node {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 120px !important;
    width: 120px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

.node:nth-child(2)::before {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.node:nth-child(3)::before {
    transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.node:nth-child(4)::before {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.node:nth-child(5)::before {
    transform: rotate(240deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="node">1</div>
<div class="node">2</div>
<div class="node">3</div>
<div class="node">4</div>
<div class="node">5</div>
```

Comment: Also, I had to use `node:nth-child(2)::before` not `node:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Yep, you're right. I updated my answer to reflect that.  Looks much better now

Comment: please don't answer typo question, help us closing them instead